# Installing gcloud / gsutil on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, apt

Looking to migrate some storage buckets from AWS S3 to Google Cloud Storage but not having any luck getting the GCP tools installed on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 VM.

Following this guide: [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#deb][1]

Primarily getting stuck here:

```
root@ubuntu18:/home/me# apt install google-cloud-sdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "google-cloud-sdk", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install google-cloud-sdk"

E: Unable to locate package google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you add the Google Cloud SDK URI first?

```
# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud Platform public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

# Update the package list
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Google Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem.  Derp.

Comment: Solved my problem as well, thanks!
@JohnHeyer, as you indicated it solved the issue you had, can you accept the answer?

Comment: works well on ubuntu!!

Comment: Also works well on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

`sudo snap install google-cloud-cli --classic`